# OnCompleteListener - OnDeleteListener -OnUpdateListener

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
try {

                   Myclass S = new S();
                    //here I give my variables
                    if (var_code !=0) {
                       MainActivity.db.
                             collection("S").
                            document("" + S).
                              set(S).
//the problem is here I want instead of add I want delete and update
                               addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The Next Match is on"+var_currentdate+ "In Town '"+var_town+"'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   }
                               })

                               .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"add operation failed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   }
                               });
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You Need To Complete The Teamcode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String message = e.getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the code of "adding" - inserting .I write instead of addOnCompleteListener I write deleteOnCompleteListener.So I will delete the values from Firestore with the delete. Also,I did with similar way the update.But I failed too,instead of addOnCompleteListener I write updateOnCompleteListener.What's really going wrong?

Comment: There is no deleteOnCompleteListener. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: to delete the data from Firebase.With that way Insert those variables into firebase.With delete to delete them and with update to create them

Comment: `addOnCompleteListener` means you are attaching a listener that is triggered when the operation is complete. the listener doesn't perform any operation by itself. the block of code you provide for it is run when the operation is complete. And in your case, you are setting some value and attaching the listener to that operation meaning when the operation of setting the value is complete, your `onComplete` block is run. if you want to update values, you need to use `update` instead of `set` and pass your data. deleting is different. read the documentations

Comment: @MehranB If you link the corresponding docs, it really sounds like an answer ;)

Comment: can you guys send me the documentations?because with so much infor and much videos I show -I still get confused on

Comment: I write instead of set(S). I write delete(S). and update(S). and that shows me as an error now

Comment: @AlexMamo Just added the docs. ek.Nik, check out my answer below. I provided links to the proper parts of the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

`addOnCompleteListener` means you are attaching a listener that is triggered when the operation is complete (either successful or failed). The listener doesn't perform any operation by itself. The block of code you provide for it is run when the operation is complete.

And in your case, you are setting some value and attaching the listener to that operation meaning when the operation of setting the value is complete, your `onComplete` block is triggered. If you want to update values, you need to use update() instead of set().

For more info about setting and updating values as well as adding documents etc. read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

[Adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

[Updating a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)

And for info regarding deleting values and documents read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)

[Deleting fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields)

### Note:

You might want to consider using `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener` instead of `addOnCompleteListener` since `addOnCompleteListener` is basically always triggered when the operation is finished regardless of whether it has been successful or has failed.

However, `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener` are pretty self-explanatory and help you handle your errors more efficiently.